# How to include images and css files from server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have my css files on a server and I want to include them.  When I had my css files local, I was using

```
@Assets.CSS("base/images.css")
```

How do I reference the css files on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/base/images.css")" />
```

**After Comment:**

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://d34gornfa0.cloudfront.net/images.css" />
```

Or, create and use an *HTML Helper*:

```
<link type="text/css" href="@Html.ResolveCSSDirectory("image.css")" />
```

Comment: in that case Razor isn't really necessary. Unless you have multiple locations, in which case you might need some server-side logic to output the proper file location.